# Python: simple function for changing screens

Tags: python, kivy

I want to reduce my code via general function for changing screens. my screens have names as numbers e.g name: "2".. when you click on certain list in bottomsheet I want to changing certain screen.

in .py

```
    def show_bottom_sheet(self):
        bs = MDListBottomSheet()
        bs.add_item("Models", lambda x: x,icon='account-group-outline')

        for y in 1,2,3,4,12,13,14,21,23,24,31,32,34,41,42,43,123,124,134,234:
            bs.add_item(f"example {y} ", lambda x= y: self.behavior(x), icon='account-group-outline')
            bs.open()

    def behavior(self, x):
        self.manager.current = str(x)
```

before my changes it was like this, but for every single number and it was too long

```
def behavior2(self):
    self.manager.current = "2"
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you be more clear about your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
def show_bottom_sheet(self):
    bs = MDListBottomSheet()
    bs.add_item("Models", lambda x: x, icon='account-group-outline')

    for y in 1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 13, 14, 21, 23, 24, 31, 32, 34, 41, 42, 43, 123, 124, 134, 234:
        bs.add_item(f"example {y} ", partial(self.behavior, y), icon='account-group-outline')
        bs.open()


def behavior(self, x, instance):
    self.manager.current = str(x)
```